# *ngFor loop through an array of arrays Angular6

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have array like this,

```
[[{"user":"1","nice":"0","sys":"1","CPU":"93","irq":"0"}, 
{"user":"1","nice":"0","sys":"1","CPU":"92","irq":"0"}, 
{"user":"1","nice":"0","sys":"1","CPU":"92","irq":"0"}, 
{"user":"1","nice":"0","sys":"1","CPU":"92","irq":"0"}], 
[{"user":"0","nice":"0","sys":"0","CPU":"91","irq":"0"}, 
{"user":"0","nice":"0","sys":"1","CPU":"91","irq":"0"}, 
{"user":"1","nice":"0","sys":"0","CPU":"91","irq":"0"}, 
{"user":"0","nice":"0","sys":"0","CPU":"90","irq":"0"}]]
```

I want to loop through this array of object in an HTML table using ngFor

```
<table class="table table-striped mt-5">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">User</th>
      <th scope="col">Nice</th>
      <th scope="col">Sys</th>
      <th scope="col">CPU</th>
      <th scope="col">IRQ</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let post of posts">
      <td>{{post.user}}</td>
      <td>{{post.nice}}</td>
      <td>{{post.sys}}</td>
      <td>{{post.CPU}}</td>
      <td>{{post.irq}}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

But my code doesn't work

Comment: Try `*ngFor="let post of posts[0]"` (not tested) but I think you can access to your nested array like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`ng-container`](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#ng-container-to-the-rescue) to hold one `ngFor` and do the second `ngFor` in the `tr` tag like this:

```
<tbody>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let group of posts">
        <tr *ngFor="let post of group">
            <td>{{post.user}}</td>
            <td>{{post.nice}}</td>
            <td>{{post.sys}}</td>
            <td>{{post.CPU}}</td>
            <td>{{post.irq}}</td>
        </tr>
    </ng-container>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 4):

Its not array of arrays, you have two arrays. if you want to iterate over the first one use the index as **`posts[0]`**

```
 <tr *ngFor="let post of posts[0]">
      <td>{{post.user}}</td>
      <td>{{post.nice}}</td>
      <td>{{post.sys}}</td>
      <td>{{post.CPU}}</td>
      <td>{{post.irq}}</td>
  </tr>
```

**[`STACBKLITZ DEMO`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fa2yh5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**